# Access 2007 - drop down box in a Report

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to create a drop-down box so that an employee can select a pre-set reason in the "RE:" field of a Report. There are only two selections that need to be in the box: "personal events" and "lack of adequate notice".

The report itself is already made and there are a number of fields that link back to the database - name, address, specific dates, etc that are already in the report. I've figured out how to make the drop-down box using the combo box function in a form but is there any way I can merge the combo box into the report?

I'm a beginner, by the way so I'm still figuring things out.

Comment: Why do you need to merge? You can add the combo/drop-down box in to the form and then take that input into your sql query as a criteria (assuming you have the column already in the tables) and output that in to the report.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your report sits on a query (query get relevant data from the table)

Steps to follow:-

1. Change the table by adding a column with the two options you just
   mentioned above
2. Add combobox to Form with items as the two options
3. Adjust your query to use these options as a criteria to change
   results returned by the query
4. Show the results in the report as you are showing right now.

If you have a code already, please post that snippet. So we can help you accordingly.

Some [reference for you to get ideas](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut19.htm)

**BUT I HAVE A DOUBT, ARE YOU TRYING TO SAY YOU WANT TO SWTICH BETWEEN TWO REPORTS BASED ON THE USER CHOICE SELECTED IN COMBOBOX?**

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, I don't want to switch between two reports. 
Your original response is more in line with what I need (to output it into the report); I don't want to switch between reports or anything like that.

I can do steps 1+2; but after that I think I've gotten a bit lost. How do I output it into the report? Thanks for clarifying things a bit, and for the link.

Comment: Alright, you are literally in the stage of binding combobox input to to your query. Also called getting a user parameter from a query. Can you take a look at this link? [parameter query combobox](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx) we could help you write the code, but then you won't have that awesome feeling when your combobox invoke the report :-D

Comment: What do you mean by output *it* into the report? Isn't your query already outputting some data to the report? All you are asking is to change that out put data a bit, aren't you?